# PHP Mongo: Search for a particular text in whole collection

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to get all documents that have a specific word either in any nested json. A document in collection looks like this;

```
Man:{
        First name: 'F-Name'
        Last name: 'L-Name'
        hobbies:{
            sports:'cricket'
            watching: 'films'
        }
        Likeness:{
            name: 'F-name'
            fruit: 'chikoo'
        }
    }
```

and there are multiple such documents in collection. 
For example I want to find all the documents that have word `F-name`. See in the above json. `F-name` is in 2 nested jsons. But it can be in only one or multiple. What is speedy and intelligent way for finding all that documents rather than giving any field or nested Json name (First name, Likeness->name in above case). Is there any way?

```
$mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$filter = [ ?? ];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);     
$res = $mng->executeQuery("Database.myName", $query);
```

**Edit 1**
On the suggestion of @Shail Paras I run the following code;

```
<?php
    $mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    $query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query(['createIndex' => ['*' => 'text']]);
    $res = $mng->executeQuery("BBC_Database.BBC", $query);
    $filter = ['$text' => ['$search' => "\"F-name\""]];
    $query1 = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);     
    $cursor = $mng->executeQuery("Database.Col", $query1);
    $filteredData = iterator_to_array($cursor);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($filteredData);
?>
```

But it gives;

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'text index required for $text query' in C:\wamp64\www-------filename.php on line 7

What is text index according to the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.. That is the error of [Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) because text search only works if indexing is created, and i think your indexing part is not working. that's why it is throwing that exception. and I'm sorry for being in hurry. but Here is your solution:

Step 1 : Create Indexes in All Documents using [Command](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executecommand.php)

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
$command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
    "createIndexes" => "Col",
    "indexes"       => [[
        "name" => "indexName",
        "key"  => ["$**" => "text"],
        "ns"   => "Database.Col",
    ]],
]);
$result = $manager->executeCommand("Database", $command);
var_dump($result->toArray()); // this will show u indexing result
```

Step 2 : Run Your query

```
$filter = ['$text' => ['$search' => "\"F-name\""]];
$query1 = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);     
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery("Database.Col", $query1);
$filteredData = iterator_to_array($cursor);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($filteredData);
```

Hope this can help you and if it did, then don't forget to read these articles:

[Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) & [Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)

Comment: Kindly do in `MongoManager` class as given in the question.

Comment: Kindly do it yourself bro.. I have just given you an idea..How to do it!! You only need to change your `$filter` variable as `$search`..

Comment: As discussed in the question that, `F-name` can be any where, in any json or any array. **What is speedy and intelligent way for finding all that documents rather than giving any field or nested Json name** You are giving json names **Likeness.name**. I want generic search.

Comment: Every time I have to make the index or only once?

Comment: have you defined `mng`? in line `$cursor = $mng->executeQuery("Database.Col", $query1);`

Comment: oh. its same variable `$manager` => `mng`.. ok i have fixed.. is it worked for you??

Comment: I am getting `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'namespace mismatch'` on line `$result = $manager->executeCommand("Database", $command);`

Comment: @amar - pls make sure you have same collection in both places: 1- `"createIndexes" => "collectionName"` and 2- `"ns"   => "Database.collectionName"`. otherwise it should be the issue of `mongodb/driver` , well i'm not sure about this.